# CSS Flex: Restrict max height of child within vertical Flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a container (**A**) with `flex-direction: column`, containing 2 child elements (**B** and **C**)

The first child (**B**) has dynamic content and its height will vary.

The second child (**C**) uses `flex-grow` to fill the remaining height of the parent container.
[image]

How can I create a child (**D**) that takes the full height of it's parent (**C**), with an overflow scroll property?

```css
div {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#A {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #DAE8FC;
  padding: 1rem;
  gap: 1rem;
}

#B {
  background-color: #D5E8D4;
}

#C {
  position: relative;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #FEF2CC;
}

#D {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!-- Content is editable to vary the content height easyly -->
<div id="A" contenteditable>
  <div id="B">
    Content Of B
  </div>
  <div id="C">
    Content Of C
    <div id="D">
      Content Of D
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will it have other content in C than D  ?

Comment: @CharlesLavalard - nope, you've got it right, the only content of C is D! The missing piece was adding `flex-grow` onto D itself - thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Given some parent height the scroll works on the inner element.

```css
#A {
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #FF0000;
}

#B {
  background-color: #00FF00;
}

#C {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #0000FF;
  height: 100%;
}

#D {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  border: solid 1px #ff0000;
  background-color: #00FFFF;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="A">
  <div id="B">
    Some variable content
  </div>
  <div id="C">
    <div id="D" style="flex-grow: 1; overflow-y: scroll; background-color: #00FFFF">
      x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

As the original snippet already included a parent height, the actual answer here is:

The inner child (**D**) also needs to include `flex-grow: 1` - thanks to Mark for the tip